# Can I cache $(window) and $(document) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance, caching

I recently read some articles regarding jQuery performance, and I came up with some weird questions.

- Can/Should I cache `$(window)`?

  If I did, would it affect `resize`, `scroll`, `width`, `scrollTop`...etc?
- Can/Should I cache `$(document)`?

  As we use a lot of mouse actions, should I do `var doc = $(document);`?
- Can I *always* cache `$(this)` in a big block of code?

  As for `var self = $(this);`, in what condition that `self` might be different from `$(this)`?

Comment: You can cache `$(window)` but did you profile to check this was useful for your application ?

Comment: using `var self = $(this)` is useful when `$(this)` might change based on scope, and you need a reference to the original `$(this)`

Comment: Please don't call it caching, because its not. Your simply saving something in to a variable. The closest thing you get to caching would be `$.cache`

Comment: I agree you shouldn't call it caching. But the jquery people just do. So we might just stick to it for better understanding.

Comment: @Johan Well, I learned the word `caching` from those 'tutorials'. If you Google `jQuery performance`, you'll probably find 99/100 of articles are saying `cache your object: var foo = $("#bar");`.

Comment: A cache is a component that transparently stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster. If this is memory or a variable, it's still caching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**All three questions:** Yes You can!

**Neccessery :**  no

**Better performance:** maybe

You could try and do a benchmark. But the reason for caching is not to search entire DOM for your selector. Looking up document and window isn't a problem because they are 2 root variables.   Caching $(this) depends on situation. See my 2nd tip.

**Always cache the parent object you run queries on:**

```
var header = $('#header');
    
var menu = header.find('.menu');
// or
var menu = $('.menu', header);
```

**It’s better to chain the jQuery methods than to cache the selectors:**

```
$('li.menu-item').click(function () {alert('test click');})
                     .css('display', 'block')
                     .css('color', 'red')
                     fadeTo(2, 0.7);
```

**Cache elements that you query often:**

```
var header = $('#header');
var divs = header.find('div');
var forms = header.find('form');
```

**A free extra performance tip:**

Selectors fastes to slowest:

```
Id > Tag > classes
```

Comment: That is what I'v been reading these days. Can you focus on the 3 questions I asked?

Comment: Well first 2 questions , No. You could try and do a benchmark. But the reason for caching is not to search entire DOM for your selector. Looking up document and window isn't a problem because they are 2 root variables.   Caching $(this) depends on situation. See my 2nd tip. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, you can cache $(window), and it does help on performance.
   Someone already did a test in jsperf.
         http://jsperf.com/jquery-window-cache

   The test result is kind of messed up, but you can still "Run test" on
   your browser to see the difference.
2. Yes, you can cache $(document) as well. I don't use $(document) much,
   but base on the test I made in jsperf
   (http://jsperf.com/document-vs-cache), caching $(document) do help on
   performance a bit too.
3. And yes, you can cache $(this). But this one is different than the
   other cahces. As you already know, value of $(this) will change
   depend different situation. For example, if you use $(this) in mouse
   listener like this....

   ```
   $(".button").on("click",function(){
      var $this = $(this);
   });
   ```

   $(this) will change when user click on the button with the class
   "button", and $("this") will become the object which clicked by
   user.

   Caching $(this) can help on performance if you use $(this) a lot
   inside the function. But remember that if you cache $(this) inside
   the function, the cache will become a local variable instead global,
   and will be destroy at the end of the function. So you won't able to
   use it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Actual question is, `Can I cache $(window) and $(document) in jQuery?`

If you want to cache the window or document for further use in the same session, yes you can.

All the variables/functions you created will be garbage collected if user closes the window/session.