# if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300) Why this not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have problem with my infinite scroll. I want execute load more before 300px of the bottom of the page.

I detect the scroll with :

```
$window.scroll(function(){
```

And in this function I have test this :

```
if (($document.height() - $window.height()) == $window.scrollTop()) {
```

But this works only when we are at footer.

Then I test this :

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300)
```

But the infinite scroll run several times between 300px and the bottom of the page.

After this, I want just test this :

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300)
```

But this not working and I don't understand. 
Do you have ideas ?

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The condition to check is simply:

`if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300){}`

Probably `==` or `===` might not work because it wont hit exact equal to condition.

**Edit:** *As requested I have added the code to prevent multi-calling the page load function. What happens is  simple unbind of the event till the new content is loaded. Once it is completed the event is bound back again. So, you can use `>` and still the load function is only called once.
I have created a simple `setTimeout` to simulate the delay from ajax request inside in your code.*

---

**[---LINK TO FIDDLE---](https://jsfiddle.net/np8n52r7/)**

---

**SEE THIS SIMPLE WORKING DEMO:**

```js
var winCached = $(window),
  docCached = $(document)

var currLeng = 0;

function addContent() {
  dettachScrollEvent();
  setTimeout(function() { //this timeout simulates the delay from the ajax post
    for (var i = currLeng; i < currLeng + 100; i++)
      $('div').append(i + '<br />');
    currLeng = i;
    console.log("called loader!");
    attachScrollEvent();
  }, 500);

}

function infiNLoader() {
  if (winCached.scrollTop() + winCached.height() > docCached.height() - 300) {
    addContent();
    //alert("near bottom! Adding more dummy content for infinite scrolling");
  }
}

function attachScrollEvent() {

  winCached.scroll(infiNLoader);
}

function dettachScrollEvent() {
  winCached.unbind('scroll', infiNLoader);
}
addContent();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: for performance reason you must first create: `var $window = $(window);` and `var $document = $(document);` and reference it in your `scroll()`. Otherwise `jQuery` will create two new objects on every `scroll` event.

Comment: @spirit Usually yes like for selecting elements inside, but since `document` and `window` are 2 root variables, I don't think the performance issue will be significant. Have a look at this SO post regarding exactly this. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836897/can-i-cache-window-and-document-in-jquery Neverthless I have made the edit, incase I am wrong and also considering that `.scroll()` creates too large a number of events.

Comment: thanks for the post. Actually my thoughts was not about performance it was about memory consumption =). I thought that when we are creating on each `scroll` event new objects we will end up with browser tab that takes more and more memory. So I made a test and it doesn't =)

Comment: Yes but you don't have solution if the scroll is only = at 300px ?

Comment: @RémiBonnet you mean your issue is multiple load correct? I'll fix that. but `==` won't work bcoz there is no guarentee if that exact value will be hit.

Comment: Thank you so much, this work :) But I have another problem with the unbind scroll. Can I use the unbind scroll for only this action ? Because I have conflit with another element who use the scroll event.

Comment: @RémiBonnet done!! made the adjustment edit. (dont forget to accept if the issue is resolved :D)